# get method on collection in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using the get backbone method on a collection but in the same file (router),in a function works while in other function doesn't work.Below the function where doesn't works

```
     var Models = {};
       var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "user/:id":"userDetails",
        "settings":"settings",//mettere id dell utente loggato
        "friends":"friends",
        "mailbox":"mailbox",
        "landscape":"landscape",
        "gestione_richieste_amic":"gestione_richieste_amic"
    },

    friends: function(){
     console.log("friend_router");
     var self=this;
      Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
      Models.utenti.fetch({
      success: function(object) {
     console.log(object);


     var view=new FriendsView({model:object}); 
    self.changePage(view);

     },
     error: function(amici, error) {

    }
    }); 

    console.log(Models.utenti);
    var cur_user=Parse.User.current().id;

    console.log(Models.utenti.get(cur_user));<--undefined, don't works here
    console.log(cur_user); 






   }   ,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this the **Asynchronous** nature of `Ajax` (fetch method).

The line where you log to the console will be executed before the collection is fetched. So you see an error.

**1st Option** - resolving the error is moving the log to inside of the `success` handler

```
friends: function () {
         console.log("friend_router");
         var self = this,
             Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
         Models.utenti.fetch({
             success: function (object) {
                 console.log(object);
                 var view = new FriendsView({
                     model: object
                 });
                 self.changePage(view);
                 console.log(Models.utenti);
                 var cur_user = Parse.User.current().id;

                 console.log(Models.utenti.get(cur_user));
                console.log(cur_user); 
             },
             error: function (amici, error) {

             }
         });
     },
```

**2nd Option** -  you might take is to bind a `sync` event on the collection..

```
initialize: function () {
     this.Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
     this.listenTo(this.Models.utenti, 'sync', this.logCollection);
     _.bindAll(this, 'logCollection');
 },
 logCollection: function () {
     console.log(this.Models.utenti);
     var cur_user = Parse.User.current().id;

     console.log(this.Models.utenti.get(cur_user)); 
    console.log(cur_user); 
 },
 friends: function () {
     console.log("friend_router");
     var self = this;
     this.Models.utenti.fetch({
         success: function (object) {
             console.log(object);
             var view = new FriendsView({
                 model: object
             });
             self.changePage(view);
         },
         error: function (amici, error) {

         }
     });
 },
```

Comment: I actually didn't fully read the question either, I was just commenting that you wrote "you have 2 options" and then wrote only one.

Comment: But i'm using all inside friends function!!If models.utenti is local variable i can view it....but i can't

Comment: The is because the Collection is still empty and the `fetch` call has not yet responded back from the response